# Evaluating the expected value of negatively correlated random variables

Tags: approximation-algorithms, randomized-algorithms, chernoff-bound, sample-complexity

A polynomial random process satisfying the following properties converts a fractional point $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathcal{P}$, $(x_i \in [0,1])$ to a random integer point $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n) \in \mathbb{Z}(\mathcal{P})$, $(X_i \in \{0,1\})$:

- $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=x_i$, for all $i \in [n]$.
- For any $S \subseteq [n]$, $\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i\in S} X_i] \leq \prod_{i \in S} x_i$ and $\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i\in S} (1-X_i)] \leq \prod_{i \in S} (1-x_i)$ (negative correlation).

An example is the dependent randomized rounding by Chekuri, Vondrak, and Zenklusen (http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4348v2.pdf).

We focus on *the dependent randomized rounding*. Given a point $x \in \mathcal{P}$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is a matroid polytope, let us assume that $X$ is the outcome of the random process (the dependent randomized rounding). Can we evaluate the value of $Pr\Big(\displaystyle \bigwedge_{i \in S} X_i=1 \Big)$  for some $S \subseteq [n]$? Shall we use sampling for this purpose?

That would be great if you can comment on this.

Comment: Are you assuming each $X_i\in [0,1]$?  Otherwise the conditions on the products seem strange...

Comment: @NealYoung, Yes, I assume $x_i \in [0,1]$ and $X_i \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: What exactly are you interested in bounding with a Chernoff-like bound?  E.g. are you interested in bounding $\Pr[\sum_i X_i \ge (1+\epsilon)\sum_i x_i]$?

Comment: What about thm's 3.2 and 3.4 of http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0097539793250767 ?

Comment: @NealYoung thank you very much for your comments. What I'm interested in is basically $Pr\Big(\displaystyle \bigwedge_{i \in S} X_i=1 \Big)$. I updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @NealYoung, To make it more concrete, I also limited the question to the _dependent randomized rounding_ by Chekuri et al.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, don't you have (for any $S$) that $$\Pr\left[\forall_{i\in S} X_i = 1\right] = \Pr\left[\prod_{i\in S} X_i = 1\right] = E\left[\prod_{i\in S} X_i\right] \le \prod_{i\in S} x_i$$ and $$\Pr\left[\forall_{i\in S} X_i = 0\right] = \Pr\left[\prod_{i\in S} (1-X_i) = 1\right] = E\left[\prod_{i\in S} (1-X_i)\right] \le \prod_{i\in S} 1-x_i?$$  These seem like about the best bounds you could hope for in general given your assumptions...

Comment: @NealYoung, correct. We know (for any $S$) that $\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i\in S} X_i]$ is less than or equal to $\prod_{i \in S} x_i$, yet the question is, how much less? (in case they aren't equal). Can we calculate $\mathbb{E}[\prod_{i\in S} X_i]$ more precisely?

Answer (score 1):

I think that in principle it would take exponential time to compute this probability exactly. Hence sampling would be the only option here, although you would have to settle for additive and multiplicative approximation here.
Can I ask you about the problem in which you need this value to be computed?